# The BackgroundWorker RunWorkerAsync method does not trigger DoWork();

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I've been trying to get the BackGroundWorker to work for hours now. I can't seem to find out why my DoWork() eventhandler isn't getting raised after calling bgw.RunWorkerAsync();

I've cut down the irrelivant code, so it's a bit easyer to read.

```
namespace FolderMonitor
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    using FolderMonitor.Properties;

    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private ExistingFileHandler exist = new ExistingFileHandler();
        private MonitoredFileHandler handler = new MonitoredFileHandler();
        private Monitor monitor;
        private BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();

        public MainForm(Monitor monitor)
        {
            this.monitor = monitor;
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeBackgroundWorker();
            txtFolderPath.Text = Settings.Default.monitoredFolder;
            txtNewFolderPath.Text = Settings.Default.destinationFolder;
            btnStop.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
        {
            bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);
            bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgw_RunWorkerCompleted);
            bgw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgw_ProgressChanged);
        }

        private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnStop.Enabled = true;
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            exist.HandleExistingFiles(txtFolderPath.Text);
            listBoxFiles.Items.Clear();
            MonitoredFileHandler.MonitoredFolderPath = txtFolderPath.Text;
            MonitoredFileHandler.DestinationFolderPath = txtNewFolderPath.Text;
            this.bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void BtnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.bgw.CancelAsync();
            btnStart.Enabled = true;
            btnStop.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            if (!worker.IsBusy)
            {
                monitor.StartFolderMonitor(txtFolderPath.Text);
            }
        }

        private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            btnStart.Enabled = true;
            btnStop.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            handler.MonitoredFiles.Add(txtNewFolderPath.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a bgw_ProgressChanged handler but you have not set this.bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed true. And will add this. But I haven't been checking for those things yet, cuz I want to get the DoWork() method to work first. The rest doesnt matter if I don't get that to work ;) but thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

`BackgroundWorker.IsBusy` will be true after its background thread been started, so it will always be true where you are testing it inside `bgw_DoWork()`. Therefore, `monitor.StartFolderMonitor(txtFolderPath.Text)` will never be called.

What are you trying to test for? I think you can just remove the `if (!worker.IsBusy)` check.

Comment: ye the if statement doesnt make sense indeed ;) but still, it doesnt even go in the bgw_DoWork() method, so removing the if statement wont do me any good. edit: what I'm eventualy trying to do is this: start a monitor that scans a folder for incoming items and moves those items to a different folder. I had this all working with no problem, but with tasks.. now I wanted to add something which is this: Whenever that method in the monitor class moves a file, add the filename to a list and display it inside a listbox.

Answer (score 1):

Aside the aforementioned IsBusy issue, the fact that StartFolderMonitor begins with start as opposed to DoFolderMonitoring or something similar, it is perhaps non-blocking therefore the DoWork handler exits immediately.

Comment: Oh wow, sorry, this is a bit stupid. But I thought it didnt go inside the DoWork method, but it actualy does. It just doesnt go inside the method while debugging over runworkerasync method. Thank you for your time:)

Answer (score 0):

> Just call
>
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
>
> before bgw.RunWorkAsync();